# How can i copy data from an endpoint which sends response as an xml to a SQL server using ADF?

Tags: python, xml, azure, azure-data-factory

I have written a code in python in Azure Functions using requests -

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree
url = "https:..."
payload = ".."
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
    'Accept': 'application/xml'
  }
def sageSessionId():

  response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, stream= True)
  tree = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)
  xmlR = ElementTree.dump(tree)
  return(xmlR)
```

The **xmlR** is a '**NoneType**' and the Azure function on invoking only returns 200 but no content (i have called the sageSessionId in the main func in the init file).
I dont know if this is the right way to do or if there is any other way in ADF to do all these.

What i want is - to copy data from an api endpoint(which returns xml body) to sql server. I thought to write a python script as I was failing to pass the required xml body through ADF Web activity. Is it possible to do this using ADF itself invoking the api from it and getting the response also in xml format then to sql server?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited with a explanation of what i exactly need. Thanks! I am new to python and programming in Azure so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **HTTP** linked service to copy data from an api endpoint (xml response) to sql server. Below are the steps,

- Create a HTTP linked service with Base URL and required authentication.

[image]

- Create source dataset in HTTP with xml format and give the relative URL
  [image]
- Create the sink dataset (for SQL server).
- Use the copy activity with the source and sink datasets created in previous steps.

[image]

- In Mapping tab of copy activity, import schema, then give the appropriate collection reference to flatten the XML response and switch to advanced editor.[image]

Thus, with HTTP linked service with xml format as dataset, we can copy api endpoint data.

**Sink Data - sql DB**
[image]